# Interpretation and meaning of ""They were speaking to each other halfcircular words at the semiround table."

Tags: idioms, phrase-request, translation

I translated a sentence to English:

> "They were speaking to each other halfcircular words at the semiround table."

In original language, this sentence is:

> "Разговаривали друг с другом за полукруглым столом полушарной лексикой"

I thought a half-circular word is a word that was said as hint, just in general, like **beating around the bush, nothing concrete**.

I want to understand how people could perceive it. What picture could people see when reading the sentence?

Comment: We probably wouldn't use half-circular. When talking about someone's speech, the use of the word 'half' would suggest they do not mean anything or haven't been thought through, like the phrase 'half-baked'. I can see there's supposed to be a pun but it's not clear. What is it in the original language?

Comment: But if it's some kind of a literary work filled with humor, I wouldn't mind reading or seeing "semi-circular". But, yes, I agree that using the idiom would sound better. I find using 'half-circular' funny and creative (if that's the author's intent).

Comment: @Natalia, my comments are merely personal opinions. And btw, I think we should copy-paste your comments to the original post in order to add details to it. I did the edits to provide you an idea of the structure, but please feel free to edit further, as needed. :)

Comment: What does "полушарная" mean in Russian?

Comment: @shin, my sister and I write illustrated stories (rather pan-stories) in the Russian, and I wanted to translate them into English.

Comment: @Rompey, there is no the word "полушарная" in the Russian. This word is adjective that was composed of two nouns: "половина" which means half and "шар" which means sphrere or ball.

Comment: As an aside, I would change the word order a little: "They were speaking  half-circular words to each other at the semi-round table." or add another word like 'in' or 'with': "They were speaking to each other in half-circular words at the semi-round table." "In" would make it sound like another language, "with" would be more like some other sort of thing like "speaking with chirps and whistles".

Comment: @ColleenV, thank you for your comment. I'll change the word order.

Comment: Dear Natalia, being a native Russian speaker I should have put my question like this: Что по-вашему означает "полушарная лексика"? Что-то из ново-русского лексикона that neither my teenage son nor I, an old stupid bean have ever happened to hear? Please write in Russian the equivalent of "полушарная лексика" as you think a Russian would grasp it. So far, I don't, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Rompey, here is a fragment from this story: "Жили-были два Недошара. Правый и Левый. Разговаривали друг с другом за полукруглым столом полушарной лексикой, то есть один пользовался левыми словами, а другой правыми. Один хотел править, другой левить. И никак не могли договориться, кто прав, кто лев". It's like a play on words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Circular Reasoning**" is a form of faulty reasoning, so "half-circular words" suggests to me that the words are being used to *sort of* make circular (faulty/deceptive) arguments. And yes, it is amusing/funny that the abstract nature of the words would match the shape of the table.

Also suggested are:  to talk "in **circles**", "**circuitously**" or to "beat **around** the bush" which all have similar meanings -- to talk in an indirect, unproductive and possibly deceptive manner.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for might be **[elliptical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elliptical)**.  It means something like "deliberately obscure" or "intentionally vague" or "cryptic", but it *also* means "shaped like an ellipse (an oval)"!

So it might be a neat play on words to say *"They spoke elliptically at a half-round table"*, because it makes a punning reference both to how they were speaking and the shape they were in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is saying that they were speaking in [**half-truths**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/half-truth). These are often used to deceive others for personal benefit.

I don't know how this is related to "half-circular words", but the "round" table referred to in the King Arthur legend implied fairness and equality of all participants.

Answer (score 0):

The expression **circular talk** is occasionally used, however the meaning is not specific. Some people think that it means a conversation that doesn't go anywhere, or is very indirect: others that it's like circular reasoning: see Stew's answer.

If you were prepeared to change the shape of the table, it would read nicely as

> Their words were circular talk at a round table.